# Deduction of templated non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-deduction

Should the compiler be able to deduce the type of the non-type template parameter of function template `f` that is defaulted to `n{}`? Which specific rule in the C++20 standard allows/mandates this?

```
template<typename = int>
struct s {
    template<typename = int>
    struct n {};

    template<n = n{}>
    constexpr int f();
};
static_assert(requires { s{}.f(); }); // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
```

Surprisingly, `MSVC` for some reason accepts the following code while the other compilers won't even allow the syntax. Is `MSVC` simply having a tea party with its imaginary friends here? And, is there a workaround that works for all 3 compilers, other than changing the type of the NTTP of `f` from `n` to `auto`?

```
template<typename = int>
struct s {
    template<typename = int>
    struct n {};

    template<n<typename> = n{}>
    constexpr int f();
};
static_assert(requires { s{}.f(); }); // clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qjTYGrrEv)

---

Regarding the workaround, one way to go about it is to add a member-type to `n` and use a requires-clause to do a manual type-constraint check. This is not the type of workaround I'm looking for, it adds too much bloat and is simply too cumbersome. Also, having to add explicit constness to the types just to evade some other compiler discrepancy isn't particularly appealing to me either.

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename = int>
struct s {
    template<typename T = int>
    struct n { using type = T; };

    template<auto N = n{}>
    requires std::same_as<decltype(N) const,
        n<typename decltype(N)::type> const>
    constexpr int f();
};
```

---

The error produced by `MSVC`:

```
<source>(9): error C2672: 's<int>::f': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(6): note: could be 'int s<int>::f(void)'
<source>(9): note: 'int s<int>::f(void)': could not deduce template argument
for '__formal'
<source>(9): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Comment: I think it's probably a bug in MSVC. It works when you substitute a non-nested class template for the template parameter (https://godbolt.org/z/fsa4T6nWq) it works with auto, just the nested class is a problem.

Comment: @jpalecek Yes, the example code is specifically set up this way. The workaround I'm looking for requires both the outer and inner class to be templated, as well as, constraining the NTTP of `f` to some type of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

C++20 [temp.arg.nontype]/1 permits class template argument deduction for template parameters:

> If the type `T` of a *template-parameter* (13.2) contains a placeholder type (9.2.9.6) or a placeholder for a deduced class type (9.2.9.7), the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration
>
> ```
> T x = template-argument ;
> ```
>
> If a deduced parameter type is not permitted for a *template-parameter* declaration (13.2), the program is ill-formed.

In the *template-parameter* `n = n{}`, the two `n`s are "placeholders for a deduced class type". The type of the template parameter, represented by the first `n`, should be deduced from the initializer `n{}`, giving it the type `n<int>`.

This paragraph doesn't specifically address whether the *template-argument* can come from a default template argument, but even MSVC doesn't think this is actually disallowed: MSVC is happy to accept it when `n` and `f` aren't nested within `s`:

```
template<typename = int>
struct n {};

template<n = n{}>
constexpr int f();

static_assert(requires { f(); });  // MSVC is fine with this
```

There is no reason why this should make a difference. MSVC probably just has a bug. It is not clear to me how to work around it.